# What database should I use with S3 as a host?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-s3

I'm completely new to s3.  Started coding on a site today.  I'm a mysql guy, but I'm not sure if I can host a mysql database on their server or what my options are.  What is my best option for database storage?

Edited to add:  I know this question sounds vague, but I literally don't know what my options are.  Can I use a mysql database on amazon's servers or am I forced to use Amazon's SimpleDB?

Comment: Do you mean S3, EC2, or AWS in general? S3 is Amazon's file storage service; EC2 is their cloud server product; AWS is their whole web-services business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 itself is not a typical data storage that you would simply use with RDBMS. It's only accessible via web service and is not a block device. I think that your best bet for hosting database on Amazon would be [Relational Database Service](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) which , in effect, is mysql.

You could also run your own mysql server on EC2 using EBS as backing store.

Also, SimpleDB is very nice but it is not a relational database. It's more like persistent hash map. It is not transactional and is [eventually consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). It belongs to category of [No SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solutions and you have to design your system in very specific ways for it.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a storage provider; you can't run your own code on it. You pay for file storage and can access it from your application, which has to be hosted elsewhere (Amazon EC2 for example).